# How to update associated planned date based upon the opportunity close date changed?

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

I have implemented a delivery delay for some of the opportunity line Item based upon the product family and opportunity close date.

But now the business wants if a user changes the close date from 8-03-2021 to 28 - 3- 2021 then the planned delivery date in Opportunity line items each Items Planned delivery date should automatically update with + 20 days. for ex if Planned delivery is 18-03-2021 it should automatically update to 7-04-2021.

Please find my code below.

```
public class HLP01_OPPLI {

    public static void updateQuantity(List<OpportunityLineItem> OppLI ){
        system.debug('-- Trigger OppLI aftIns --');
        system.debug(OppLI);
        
        Set<OpportunityLineItem> OpplineItemUPD= new Set<OpportunityLineItem>();        
        List<string> listOppId=new List<string>();   
        List<string> listOppliId=new List<string>(); 
        
        
        // List opp id        
        for(OpportunityLineItem OppLIIter:OppLI){            
            listOppId.add(OppLIIter.OpportunityId);
            listOppliId.add(OppLIIter.id);
        }        
        // eliminer les Oppli du CPQ (family == null)
        List<OpportunityLineItem> oppliFamily = [select id,Product2.Family,opportunityId, quantity from OpportunityLineItem where id in: listOppliId AND Product2.Family != null];
        system.debug('list Opportunity oppliFamily ' +oppliFamily);
        system.debug('lancre2'+listOppId.size());
        List<Opportunity> ListOppContract = [SELECT id, TECH_Parent_Opp_contract__c ,
                                            (SELECT id, quantity, OpportunityID FROM OpportunityLineItems Where Product2.Family='Contracts')
                                            FROM Opportunity where TECH_Parent_Opp_contract__c in:listOppId and TECH_Contract_Opp_Created__c=true];
        
        system.debug('list Opportunity contract '+ListOppContract);
        
        for(OpportunityLineItem oppIter : oppliFamily){
            for(Opportunity oppContract : ListOppContract){
                if(oppIter.opportunityId == oppContract.TECH_Parent_Opp_contract__c){
                    List<OpportunityLineItem> LineItem = oppContract.OpportunityLineItems;
                    if(!LineItem.isempty()){
                        LineItem[0].quantity=oppIter.quantity;
                        OpplineItemUPD.add(LineItem[0]);
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
        system.debug(OpplineItemUPD); 
        update new List<OpportunityLineItem>(OpplineItemUPD);
    }
    
    public static void updatePlannedDate(List<OpportunityLineItem> OppLI){
        
        List<Id> lstPrdId = new List<Id>();
        List<Id> lstOPPId = new List<Id>();        
        For(OpportunityLineItem oneOppli : OppLI){
            lstPrdId.add(oneOppli.Product2Id);
            lstOPPId.add(oneOppli.OpportunityId);
        }
        
        // Map Product
        Map<id,Product2> mapPrd2=new Map<id,Product2>([Select id, Level_1_family__c from Product2 where id in: lstPrdId]);
        // Map OPP
        Map<id,Opportunity> mapOPP=new Map<id,Opportunity>([Select id, CloseDate from Opportunity where id in: lstOPPId]);
        
        For(OpportunityLineItem oneOppliF : OppLI){
            If(oneOppliF.ServiceDate == null){
                // Delay
                oneOppliF.ServiceDate = mapOPP.get(oneOppliF.Opportunityid).closedate + getDeliveryDelay(mapPrd2.get(oneOppliF.Product2Id).Level_1_family__c);
            }
        }        
    }
    
    public static Integer getDeliveryDelay(String productFamily) {
        if      (productFamily == null || productFamily == '')  return 42;
        else if (productFamily == 'Trailer')                    return 28;
        else if (productFamily == 'Diesel Truck')               return 28;
        else if (productFamily == 'Engineless')                 return 42;
        else if (productFamily == 'Direct Drive')               return 28;
        else if (productFamily == 'Contracts')                  return 0;
        else if (productFamily == 'LCV')                        return 28;
        else                                                    return 15;
    }
}
```

Please advise how I can Implement this.

Thanks

Comment: Does you `HLP01_OPPLI` static methods get called from a Trigger or another service?

Comment: @TSmith yes in a trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When called from a Trigger, you can either pass the `old` and `new` context directly to your static methods or do the work elsewhere, up to you. In short, you should look to calculate the difference in days against the old and new `CloseDate`.

```
Integer difference = Trigger.oldMap.get(opportunityLineItem.Id).CloseDate.daysBetween(Trigger.newMap.get(opportunityLineItem.Id).CloseDate);
```

You could refactor the signature on `updatePlannedDate()` to accept a `Map` or else separate your concerns by keeping the existing method for inserts and a new method for updates (extensions due to Users modifying the CloseDate).

If extension, you can use [Date.addDays()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm)

```
updatedLineItem.ServiceDate = updatedLineItem.ServiceDate.addDays(difference);
```